# add two group into one group in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have two groups like below, theyh have different data. Based on both I need to create an xml file .

How can I write a for-loop for both groups and generate a single xml file?

```cs
var groups = checkFile.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { DocNum = x.Field<int>("orderid"), Type = x.Field<string>("Type"), ProdName = x.Field<string>("ProdName"), Status = x.Field<string>("Status"), productno = x.Field<string>("productno"), uom = x.Field<string>("uom"), customer = x.Field<string>("customer"), remark = x.Field<string>("remark"), U_JobNumber = x.Field<string>("U_JobNumber"), U_SalesPerson = x.Field<string>("U_SalesPerson"), U_POnum = x.Field<string>("U_POnum"), U_JobType = x.Field<string>("U_JobType"), PlannedQty = x.Field<decimal>("PlannedQty"), OriginNum = x.Field<int?>("OriginNum"), orderdate = x.Field<DateTime>("orderdate"), duedate = x.Field<DateTime>("duedate"), DocTotal = x.Field<decimal>("DocTotal") });

var groups2 = checkFile2.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { DocNum = x.Field<int>("DocNum") });

//now i need to take both group data inside this loop to print the file
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    var stringwriter = new StringWriter();
    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringwriter, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
    {
        xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Root");

        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

    }
    var xml = stringwriter.ToString();
    XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
    docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
    docSave.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(@SystemSettings.ImportBankStatementPendingFolderPath, "DocNum -" + group.Key.DocNum + ".xml"));
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Obviously this code isnt `<!-- language: lang-html -->`

Comment: How do you intend to associate the two lists of groups? By Index? By key? How would you handle left over objects or other conflicts?

Comment: there is a common index in both table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
           DataTable checkFile = new DataTable();

            var groups = checkFile.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new
            {
                DocNum = x.Field<int>("orderid"),
                Type = x.Field<string>("Type"),
                ProdName = x.Field<string>("ProdName"),
                Status = x.Field<string>("Status"),
                productno = x.Field<string>("productno"),
                uom = x.Field<string>("uom"),
                customer = x.Field<string>("customer"),
                remark = x.Field<string>("remark"),
                U_JobNumber = x.Field<string>("U_JobNumber"),
                U_SalesPerson = x.Field<string>("U_SalesPerson"),
                U_POnum = x.Field<string>("U_POnum"),
                U_JobType = x.Field<string>("U_JobType"),
                PlannedQty = x.Field<decimal>("PlannedQty"),
                OriginNum = x.Field<int?>("OriginNum"),
                orderdate = x.Field<DateTime>("orderdate"),
                duedate = x.Field<DateTime>("duedate"),
                DocTotal = x.Field<decimal>("DocTotal")
            });
            DataTable checkFile2 = new DataTable();

            //now i need to take both group data inside this loop to print the file
            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                List<DataRow> groups2 = checkFile2.AsEnumerable().Where(x => group.Key.DocNum == x.Field<int>("DocNum")).ToList();
            }
```